# Bitmap not being painted in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I have a window using Win32 and in the message handler I have a case for WM_PAINT, so that a bitmap is drawn in the window. However on running the bitmap is not drawn, is there something I am missing? Do I need to manually send the WM_PAINT message?

Here is the code I have: http://pastebin.com/bi48LB0U

and this is the WM_PAINT case:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    bmp = LoadBitmap(hInst, L"C:\\example.bmp");
    memDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    SelectObject(memDCExercising, bmp);
    BitBlt(hDC, 100, 100, 500, 500, memDCExercising, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(memDCExercising);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
```

Comment: `assert(bmp != NULL);`

Comment: Doomed to fail, LoadBitmap() takes the resource ID, not a path name.  You need LoadImage() instead.  And yes, always check winapi return values, assert() at a minimum.

Comment: How can I make a resource ID from my file name?

Comment: [LoadBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033.aspx): *"A pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the **name of the bitmap resource** to be loaded. Alternatively, this parameter can consist of the **resource identifier** in the low-order word and zero in the high-order word."*

Comment: You're asking the wrong question: There is no way to create a resource ID for an file residing on disk. Resource IDs are available for resources compiled into a binary image only. If you want to load a file from disk, use [LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045.aspx) instead.

Comment: You really truly do not want to load an image from disk in `WM_PAINT`. That can be called a lot. Load it once and hold on to the HBITMAP.

Comment: I have it working from loading the resource once. Would I be able to modify the resource and reload it at runtime? My program wants to be able to display the original image and a modified image...

Comment: You do not seem to understand what the term [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468900.aspx) refers to, when used with Windows binaries.

Comment: On a side note, you are leaking the `HBITMAP` returned by `SelectObject()`.  You need to save and restore it before calling `DeleteDC()`: `HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(memDCExercising, bmp); ...  SelectObject(memDCExercising, oldBmp); DelectDC(memDCExercising);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bitmap doesn't show, because your call to `LoadBitmap` returns `NULL`, due to an invalid *lpBitmapName* argument. From the documentation for [LoadBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033.aspx):

> *lpBitmapName* [in]: A pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the **name of the bitmap resource** to be loaded. Alternatively, this parameter can consist of the **resource identifier** in the low-order word and zero in the high-order word. The [**MAKEINTRESOURCE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648029.aspx) macro can be used to create this value.

In other words: `LoadBitmap` can only load bitmaps from [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468900.aspx) of type [RT_BITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009.aspx) (or predefined bitmaps provided by the system). If you need to load a bitmap from disk, use [LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045.aspx) instead.

If you need to load image data other than plain bitmap files, consider using the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx).